# Matlab installation is stuck -- how do I abort it?

Tags: installation, matlab

It does not advance. There is no "cancel" button.  Is there a way to escape the installation process, perhaps via a terminal command or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/13441

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to kill applications](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13441/how-to-kill-applications)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this as described in the other question:

- In System->Admin you have an application called System Monitor
- you can also kill with `xkill`. Just go to the "run" dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), type in `xkill` and your mouse pointer will change to an "x". Point on the application that you want to kill and click, and it'll be killed.

Answer (score 0):

Run this:

```
ps -e
```

Find the process `matlab-support.` and its PID

Kill it using:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```