# How to kill a program?

Tags: steam, 17.04, xkill

How I can kill a program corectlly?

Because when I use `xkill` very often it's closed incorectlly.

**Scenario:**

I have a game, game lags, I can't close it normally, im forced, to use forced kill, in this scenario `xkill` should be good but when I close a game (in steam), steam still thinks that game is opened, and I can't launch it again.

[image: Error that is shown]

Any solutions? And please no answers like reboot, because it's not I'm focused to.

Comment: you want terminate not kill, I'm not sure of the command. I use my sysmonitor to terminate programs

Comment: Possibe duplicate of [How to kill applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13441/how-to-kill-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `terminal`...

```
ps auxc # to determine the PID (process ID) or process name
```

**example...**

```
           PID                                                     name
            |                                                       |
            V                                                       V
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0 205712  7904 ?        Ss   Jun17   0:05 systemd
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun17   0:00 kthreadd
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jun17   0:00 kworker/0:0H
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun17   0:01 ksoftirqd/0
root         7  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun17   2:57 rcu_sched
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun17   0:00 rcu_bh
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jun17   0:00 migration/0
r
```

**By process ID...**

```
sudo kill -HUP PID # the nice way
sudo kill -9 PID   # if -HUP doesn't work
```

**or by process name...**

```
sudo killall -HUP process_name # the nice way
sudo killall -9 process_name   # if -HUP doesn't work
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this:

- find the pid of application is having problems 
  ps - A | grep someTextToFind

Example: if your app is doubleCommander

```
 ps -A | grep doubl 
 2727 ?        00:04:06 doublecmd
 kill -9 2727
```

If in this way the program also is running.

click on dashboard,
search
System Monitor

- find your application
- click right botton
- Kill
  I hope this can help!