# How to force quit the files program

Tags: files, xkill

Cant use pkill or xkill, so please answer my question fast

Comment: please read [ask] and then [edit] you question accordingly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to kill a program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927105/how-to-kill-a-program)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pkill -9`, the `-9` will forcefully exit the hanged app, instead of waiting for it to gracefully exit. Be careful though, this may lead to data loss in case the program was working on some files. Don't use this option by default unless the program has hung as in question.

`-9` stands for SIGKILL. It's one of POSIX signals that can be sent to the processes. When you press Ctrl-C in your console, normally SIGINT is sent (interrupt), this allows program to run any custom code to stop gracefully. On the other hand SIGKILL leaves no such chance and terminates the process immediately, which is useful in case the process is hung and won't respond to signals like SIGINT.

Comment: Why `-9` specifically?

Comment: @Puspam I edited my answer to explain that